# Execute function after clicking a button in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button "open window" on the website,  that opens a new window, in which there is other button. And if user closes this window, nothing happens. But if he presses this button - window closes, and a function is executed on the site itself.

Hope you understand me, thanks!

```
<input type="button" value="New window" onclick="createWindow();"/>
<a id="done"></a>
<script>
function createWindow() {
  var win = window.open('', 'popup', 'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,resisable=no,srollbars=yes,width=1050,height=600');
  content = '<input type="button" value="call Function" onclick="done();"/>';
  content += 'this button should call done() function';
  win.document.write(content);
}

function done() {
    document.getElementById('done').text = 'done!';
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qp0v2x8/4/

Comment: please share some tried code

Comment: Can you be a little more clearer. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim sure! http://jsfiddle.net/5qp0v2x8/4/

Comment: @johnnylak trying to call done() function: http://jsfiddle.net/5qp0v2x8/4/

Comment: the function `done()` should exist in the *new* window.

Comment: @Wreigh i want to call this function in main window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is change your `onclick` listener:

```
onclick="window.opener.done();"
```

[Learn more about `window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)